# Mysql innoDB keeps crashing

Tags: mysql, innodb

My database (mysql) server keeps crashing / restarting and I am at a loss of what to do.  I keep getting the following in my dbname.org.err file:

```
131205 18:49:05 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/les.lesplan.org.pid ended
131205 18:50:12 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
131205 18:50:12 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131205 18:50:12 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131205 18:50:12 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131205 18:50:12 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
131205 18:50:12 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
131205 18:50:12 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131205 18:50:12 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131205 18:50:12 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
131205 18:50:12  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131205 18:50:13 InnoDB: 5.5.32 started; log sequence number 94296300
131205 18:50:13 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
131205 18:50:13 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
131205 18:50:13 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
131205 18:50:14 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
131205 18:50:14 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.32-cll'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
131206 07:32:53 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
131206 07:32:53 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
131206  7:32:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131206  7:32:54 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131206  7:32:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131206  7:32:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
131206  7:32:54 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
131206  7:32:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131206  7:32:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131206  7:32:54 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
131206  7:32:54  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
131206  7:32:54  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131206  7:32:55 InnoDB: 5.5.32 started; log sequence number 94790638
131206  7:32:55 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
131206  7:32:55 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
131206  7:32:55 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
131206  7:32:55 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
131206  7:32:55 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.32-cll'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
131206 07:33:07 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
131206 07:33:07 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
131206  7:33:07 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131206  7:33:07 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131206  7:33:07 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131206  7:33:07 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
131206  7:33:07 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
131206  7:33:07 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131206  7:33:07 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131206  7:33:07 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
131206  7:33:07  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
131206  7:33:08  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131206  7:33:09 InnoDB: 5.5.32 started; log sequence number 94790648
131206  7:33:09 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
131206  7:33:09 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
131206  7:33:09 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
131206  7:33:09 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
131206  7:33:09 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.32-cll'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
131206 07:38:38 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
131206 07:38:38 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
131206  7:38:38 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131206  7:38:38 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131206  7:38:38 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131206  7:38:38 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
131206  7:38:38 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
131206  7:38:38 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131206  7:38:38 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131206  7:38:38 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
131206  7:38:38  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
131206  7:38:38  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131206  7:38:39 InnoDB: 5.5.32 started; log sequence number 94790674
131206  7:38:39 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
131206  7:38:39 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
131206  7:38:39 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
131206  7:38:39 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
131206  7:38:39 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.32-cll'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
root@les [/var/lib/mysql]#
```

The server 'crashes' and restarts at seemingly random intervals although it does happen around 7:30 am (+/- 30 minutes) more then other times it seems.

There are no cron jobs running anywhere near this time.

Any help would be appreciated!

ss

Comment: In one of your comments below you said you "ended up deleting and restoring from an old backup".  Did that stop your mysql from crashing again?  Do you have any clue what might've been causing the crashes?

Comment: Maybe related, [systemd not shutting down MariaDB properly?](https://serverfault.com/q/929030/145545) These are the reasons the question should be asked on the proper site. This answer lacks an analysis of potential root causes of the problem. All you get are anecdotes that one developer found works for them.

Answer (score 7):

Drop your ib_log files and Put innodb_force_recovery=6 in config file  and restart your mysql it will resolve

Comment: These are very dramatic steps and not justified at all based on the amount of information currently available about the specific problem being encountered here.

Comment: @brokenspoke On this site if it worked it is proper "editique" to click on the check mark by this answer to mark it as "accepted" (equivalent to "solved"). :)

Comment: It was never resolved so I did not check it... I thougth it was fixed but alas the issue kept coming back.  I ended up deleting and restoring from an old backup.  Thanks for the obvious tip though.

Comment: How/where do I drop the "ib_log files"?

Comment: Please note that innodb_force_recovery=5 or 6 are potentially destructive! Try with 1 first, move to 2, 3, and 4 first. Each is more powerful than the last but 5 and 6 can cause corruption. Use 5/6 with caution!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that from time to time, memory usage would spike (I'm guessing that this was because of a dramatic spike in apache child processes) and this would cause memory pressure. The out-of-memory killer would choose mysql to close down, because it was (usually) the biggest memory user in the system.

So to fix, I

- got more memory
- fine tuned Apache to control the number of child processes that were spun up.

Comment: additionally you can set `/proc/$(pidof mysqld)/oom_adj` to -17 so oom-killer doesn't kill mysqld. It's better to kill apache than mysqld. See https://twindb.com/oom-killer-or-how-to-fail-at-start/