# Wordpress database shutdowns

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-ec2

I've been having problems with one of my site. Every so often it an error comes up when I load my site "Database Connection Failed".
I am using a Amazon Linux server t2.micro instance.
Please can someone help I am desperate. I have no idea what is the problem and I am quite new at this stuff so I don't want to make any changes without knowing and I lose data. 
Thanks 
My mysql log file:

```
170103 18:00:02  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2104460177
170103 18:00:02  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the       database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74   75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
170103 18:00:02  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
170103 18:00:03 InnoDB: 5.5.52 started; log sequence number 2104460177
170103 18:00:03 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
170103 18:00:03 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
170103 18:00:03 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
170103 18:00:04 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
170103 18:00:04 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.52'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL   Community Server (GPL)
170104 09:09:11 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
170104 09:09:11 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
170104 09:27:17 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from  /var/lib/mysql
170104  9:27:17 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.52) starting  as process 11744 ...
170104  9:27:17 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170104  9:27:17 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170104  9:27:17 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170104  9:27:17 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170104  9:27:17 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170104  9:27:17 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170104  9:27:17 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170104  9:27:17 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
170104  9:27:17  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
170104  9:27:17  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
170104  9:27:18 InnoDB: 5.5.52 started; log sequence number 2123585383
170104  9:27:18 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
170104  9:27:18 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
170104  9:27:18 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
170104  9:27:18 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
170104  9:27:18 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.52'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL  Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql innoDB keeps crashing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484630/mysql-innodb-keeps-crashing)

Comment: Basically from what I can see in Amazon instance screenshot it shutdowns mysql because it is out of memory. Is there a way to limit this without changing the memory of the server?

Comment: For now I have created a swap of 2GB to see if it makes a difference. 2 hours since I did it seems fine. The issue is when the homepage is loaded it takes about 200-300MB of memory

Comment: So? What do you expect to find here? Your website needs thoose 300 MB? Nobody can tell with givven informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MySQL seems to have not enough RAM.

Let's say you got a guy (mysql) who carries a package of stones(data in mysql) from point a to point b over a bridge.
By the times you add more stones(more data) to the package. 
And maybe there are also more guys (more mysql instances, because more visitors on your website) on the street.

Then imagine a bridge where all this guys have to pass, which has a weight limit (RAM).

So only a few guys can walk over the bridge and others are told to either wait or (if there are too many guys waiting) go to hell with their packages.

You may either delete some data or you may limit the amounts of users or you can try to optimize the packages.

Do you really need to carry all the data or is there a way to produce the data faster?

For the second option read about mysql indexes.